# Setters/Getters not setting/getting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have a model.h and model.m to keep my data and variables which various view controllers access for data(Using MVC). The problem is, When i try to set and get the variables from them, They are always 0. I'm obviously done something wrong, but have no idea.

Here is my model.h and model.m (changed names so its easier.

model.h

```
@interface modeler : NSObject
{
   int abc;
   int def;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) int abc;
@property (nonatomic,assign) int def;
```

model.m

```
#import "modeler.h"
@interface modeler()
@end
@implementation modeler
@synthesize abc = _abc;
@synthesize def = _def;
```

Thats how i set up the two variables, here are the view controllers.
vc.h

```
#import "modeler.h"
@interface vcViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) modeler *datas;
@end
```

vc.m

```
@interface vcViewController ()
@end
@implementation vcViewController
@synthesize datas = _datas;
```

This is how im trying to set them to something in vc.m

```
NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
NSLog(@"1-%i",selectedRowIndex.row);
_datas.abc = selectedRowIndex.row;
NSLog(@"2-%i",_datas.abc);
```

The selected row prints out 2, but the _data.abc is always 0. What did i miss? I am guessing its not calling it, maybe because its an instance of it ? Any quick tips?

Comment: Please note that best practice is to always use self.property, instead of _property, when you want to assign or read your properties. Use _property only if you write a custom getter/setter method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see where you're setting the view controller's `datas` property (or the `_datas` ivar) to an instance of your `modeler` class. If that's not happening, `_datas.abc` is a message to nil -- so using it as a setter does nothing and using it as a getter returns 0.

In addition, you're declaring `abc` and `def` as ivars on your `modeler` class, and then declaring properties with the same names but different ivars (`_abc` and `_def`). This almost certainly isn't causing the problem you're seeing, but is bound to lead to confusion later. It'd be better to either not declare ivars (and let the `@synthesize` directives take care of that) or not specify ivars in your `@synthesize` directives (so that the same-named ivars are used by default. I tend to prefer the former.

Furthermore, it's also probably not connected to your problem, but it's generally a good thing to use generated accessors instead of ivars unless you have a good reason not to. (That is, use `self.datas` instead of `datas`.)

Comment: Thanks! You were right with the first line. I forgot about     obj = [[SomeObj alloc] init]; ! I knew it was something simple, That line made my whole code work :) But great tips to help me as well!

Comment: Though I realised that when i add another viewcontroller, it cant access the same as its a new instance :( need to keep the same instance throughout the app.

Answer (score 3):

You're telling the compiler to use variables `_abc` and `_def` in the @synthesize directive, so the setters won't touch the instance variables `abc` and `def`. I'm not seeing the exact problem, but you're definitely confusing yourself and/or the compiler by having properties and instance variables with the same names, but using different ivars to back the properties. Also, try not to access the ivars directly, as you're doing with `_datas` in the last snippet. You've created accessors, so use them. Once you've done that, I expect that your problems will go away.

Comment: Thanks! Great tips for beset practice.